# Is it bad to use a let's encrypt certificate outside its scope?

Tags: certificate, digital-signature, letsencrypt

I have a let's encrypt certificate issued for my website,

Since I have this certificate's private key, I could use it to sign other stuff like files, etc...

(Assuming I don't leak the private key, of course)
Could this somehow compromise the security of the certificate?
Or could this have some bad unintended consequence that I fail to grasp at the moment?

Comment: The only huge read flag is the fact the certificate would expire every 90 days.

Comment: The Let's Encrypt certificate contains [extended] usage description elements which limits what you can use the cert/private key for. Or to be precise you can use the private key for whatever you want but e.g. a document or software signature would be shown as invalid if you try to verify such a signature.